# Replacing 3/8 inch hardwood with 3/4 inch hardwood

Tags: floor, hardwood-floor

We are working to replace our existing first floor which has a section of 3/8 hardwood by the front door.  We want to use 3/4 inch hardwood.  My question is the door frame comes right down to the wood now, I am assuming I need to cut out the bottom of the frame to allow room for the wider new floor?  Or should we reconsider using 3/8 hardwood again?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. A picture of where the wood meets the door frame would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You should buy the 3/4" - [Low-cost hardwood flooring... what's the catch?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/85091/low-cost-hardwood-flooring-whats-the-catch/85099#85099).

All you will need is a jamb saw - [the overkill and easy one](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/85091/low-cost-hardwood-flooring-whats-the-catch/85099#85099).

The [traditional jamb saw](http://www.homedepot.com/p/QEP-Undercut-and-Jamb-Saw-with-High-Carbon-Steel-Blade-10096Q/100546955).

[image]

And I used to use the tradition saw but moved on to using a Dremel with a wood bit.

[image]

Now all that you have to do is uninstall old wood and then get a scrap of the new wood, lay saw on top of new wood on each jamb and cut.  I would plan on about 5 minutes per jamb - if you have experience maybe half the time.

Answer (score 0):

In support of the previous post regarding using a dremel. I came across this video for a Dremel Multi-max when I was looking for a tool to scrape up vinyl tile from a hardwood floor. This was not what I needed but shows you exactly what to do for cutting your door jambs.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fyceo57suYE
Hope this helps.